# react-router-dom, component not rendering but only <App> shows instead

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

App.js:-

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
 
 <h1>App screen</h1>

    <Routes>
    <Route path="/projectDashboard"  component={ProjectScreen} ></Route>
    <Route  path="/" component={HomeScreen} ></Route>
    </Routes>


  </BrowserRouter>
  );
```

Output that i get:-

I can only see the h1 tag. The routes don't work. Whenever I enter "localhost:3000/projectDashboard" it autocorrect and sends me to "/"

I've looked around other answers and have tried setting the exact variable as well but the issue still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RRDv6 `Route` components render their components on the `element` prop ***as JSX***, the `component` and `render` props no longer exist.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/projectDashboard" element={<ProjectScreen />} />
  <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
</Routes>
```

For reference [Routes & Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

> ```
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactElement | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string;
> }
> ```